# Concat two MP4 files (side by side) with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, editing, encoding

I'm trying to concat two videos, side by side, using ffmpeg. One of them is `1280x720`, and the other `1920x1080`. One will be left, one will be right side. The higher resolution will be resized to the lower resolution one.

What is the command to do that?

I tried this command (they used 4 videos, I tried to edit it for 2), but somewhere is wrong and it cuts the first video:

```
ffmpeg -i activity.mp4 -i mobile.mp4 -filter_complex " nullsrc=size=2560x720 [base];[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1280x720 [upperleft]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1280x720 [upperright]; [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=720" -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233832/merge-two-video-clips-into-one-placing-them-next-to-each-other/521878#521878

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i activity.mp4 -i mobile.mp4 -filter_complex " nullsrc=size=2560x720 [base];[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1280x720 [upperleft]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1280x720 [upperright]; [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; [tmp1][upperright] overlay=x=720" -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

The `shortest` should be applied only to the first overlay.

Also, you can skip scale for the video which is already 1280x720. This output will only audio from one of the inputs.

Comment: Your command gives me the same output as before! Did you forget to change anything?!

Comment: Command corrected.

Comment: No still not working. I guess `x=1280` for `shortest` which works now.

Comment: Heh. I did not check your co-ordinates.